# Does StackExchange.Redis support .NET 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, redis

I haven't found anything that confirms/denies whether StackExchange.Redis supports **.NET 4 Client Profile**.

I experimented with StackExchange.Redis for .NET 4 Client Profile many moons ago and it worked fine.  I tried again today and got the following compilation error:

> Warning       The primary reference **"StackExchange.Redis" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime**, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" **which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client**". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "StackExchange.Redis" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1819

I'm using Nuget v1.0.488

Unfortunately, upgrading isn't an option right now (it's a crazy world, I know :).

Comment: I upgraded the Microsoft.Bcl.Async and Microsoft.Bcl.Build nuget packages to their latest versions, v1.0.168 and v1.0.21 respectively, and this fixed the compilation error.  Though the question still stands.. is client profile officially supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, SE.Redis **could** work with the 4.0 client profile, but for some reason the [_net40 project](https://github.com/thepirat000/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis_Net40/StackExchange.Redis_Net40.csproj#L12) is targeting the full 4.0 Framework.

I just tried by downloading SE.Redis code, changing the target framework to 4.0 client profile, and it compiled successfully.

[image]

I've also ran all the tests targeting the client profile 4.0 and all passed OK.

[SE.Redis Issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/96) probably related.